# Refresh binding source data in C#

Tags: c#, bindingsource

I have wrote an application which is connected to an SQL server. There is a function which list out one of the table's rows in a `DataGridView`. This `DataGridView` is bound to a BindingSource which is connected to the table directly via a `DataSet`. It has been clicked via GUI.

My problem is, when something changes in the table, the `DataSource` is not refreshing. Not even I edit something via my application or just delete a row it still stands there even if the SQL table does not contains anymore.

I have wrote a refresh procedure which have been called every time I click on the table view menu or use the refresh button, it looks like that:

```
public void SrvMgmtRefresh()
{
    string select = "select * from ServersInput";
    srvMgmtDataGridView.DataSource = null;
    SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(select, con);
    DataSet DS = new DataSet();
    sqlDataAdapter.Fill(DS, "ServersInput");
    srvMgmtDataGridView.DataSource = DS.Tables[0];
}
```

Does anyone have any idea what I have did wrong? I see in the application that it reload the content of the table but it still not refresh.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: From your code it looks like you don't use a bindingsource, but use the datatable from a dataset directly. I would use a bindingsource between the grid and the datatable, they handle this much better. When the underlying data changes you can do MyBindingSource.EndEdit() if neccesarry

Comment: @GuidoG Thank you for your answer and I have deleted the sql-server tag. I have added EndEdit() tag at the modification but unfortunately still not refresh the edited column.
It looks like that now:
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
            {
                serversInputBindingSource.EndEdit();
                serversInputTableAdapter.Update(this.appData.ServersInput);
                MessageBox.Show("Saved successfully.", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                SrvMgmtRefresh();
            }

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
 DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("ProcedureName", _context.Database.GetConnectionString()))
        {
            sda.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            sda.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new 
            SqlParameter("@isMedicationPerscriber", SqlDbType.Bit)).Value = 
            filteringParams.IsMedicationPerscriber;
            sda.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new 
            SqlParameter("@isInpersonSession", SqlDbType.Bit)).Value = 
            filteringParams.InpersonSession;
            sda.Fill(ds);
        }
        int totalRecords = Convert.ToInt32(ds.Tables[1].Rows[0][0]);
        var items = ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
                     .Select(dataRow => new User
                     {                                                 
                         ZipCode = dataRow.Field<string>("ZipCode"),
                         IsDeleted = dataRow.Field<bool>("IsDeleted"),
                         IsConnected = dataRow.Field<bool>("IsConnected"),
                         Latitude = dataRow.Field<double?>("Latitude"),
                         Longitude = dataRow.Field<double?>("Longitude"),
                     }).Where(x => x.UserId != Guid.Parse(filteringParams.UserId)).ToList();
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).